# how to send the auto email in selected date without refreshing a page in php

Tags: php, html

I have to send 3 auto emails to students each day as a notification email at the interval of 24 hours in php.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronjob) to do this for you.

Comment: how cronjob is works,i m new to this technology.

Comment: then have a look at the documentation

Comment: This is very different per host. For further specifications you should google how to do this with your host.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using cpanel server. First you create a php script to send a mail. This is a very basic one. If you need you can use the following example which I have extracted from php.net

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

To setup a cron job you do not need to any coding. Please follow this video or search "How to setup cron in cpanel" in google.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_UAp80UrPY